# dynamic jquery click functions

Tags: jquery

i have small script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('a').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#iframe2').show(1000);
        $('#iframe2').attr('src', "http://www.htp-crm.pl/");
        $(this).hide(1000);
      }); 
    });
</script>
```

and html:

```
<a href="#" id="1">LINK1</a><br>
<a href="#" id="2">LINK2</a><br>
<a href="#" id="3">LINK3</a><br>
1<iframe id="iframe1" style="display: none;"></iframe><br>
2<iframe id="iframe2" style="display: none;"></iframe><br>
3<iframe id="iframe3" style="display: none;"></iframe><br>
```

How can i do this by dynamic function?
It will always be the same:
link with id=1 show iframe1
link with id=2 show iframe2
...
link with id=27 show iframe27

---

I use this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('a').click(function (e) {
            var linkId=$(this).attr('class');
            e.preventDefault();
            $('.show_km_'+linkId).show(1000);
            $('.show_km_'+linkId).attr('src', "calendar_files/index-km.php?id='.$row['iid'].'");
            $(this).hide(1000);
        }); 
    });
</script>
```

I use this script to show google distance between me and selected address.
if iframe have 'display: none' why i have a question to location permission ?
I thought the question might come after i click link to show iframe :(
Can I change something here?

// OK, i repair google maps script :). Thanks everybody to show me how to change script. Best regards!

Comment: I would think from his question its pretty obvious what hes tried..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this....

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('a').click(function (e) {
            var linkId=$(this).attr('id');
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#iframe'+linkId).show(1000);
            $('#iframe'+linkId).attr('src', "http://www.htp-crm.pl/");
            $(this).hide(1000);
        }); 
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over your anchors to get the `id` and assign that `id` to the iframe that you want to show:

```
$('a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $('iframe#' + id).show();
})
```

Comment: You don't need to use `each`.  `click` (or `on("click")` will iterate over the selected elements anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using `data` to reference the link between the anchors and the iframes, like this...

```
<a href="#" data-iframe="iframe1">LINK1</a><br>
<a href="#" data-iframe="iframe2">LINK2</a><br>
<a href="#" data-iframe="iframe3">LINK3</a><br>
1<iframe id="iframe1" style="display: none;"></iframe><br>
2<iframe id="iframe2" style="display: none;"></iframe><br>
3<iframe id="iframe3" style="display: none;"></iframe><br>
```

then you can reference the data in the `click` handler like this...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("a").on("click", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var $iframe = $("#" + $(this).data("iframe"));
            $iframe.show(1000);
            $iframe.attr("src", "http://www.htp-crm.pl/");
            $(this).hide(1000);
        }); 
    });
</script>
```

I'd also recommend not using numbers for IDs.  Apart from the fact it's not friendly to read as it doesn't tell you anything about what it is, some browsers don't like it.

Comment: You're right. I wonder to change ID for some 'class' or 'data'. Thanks.